# «На русском» или «на русский»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, склонение, падежи

Я где-то прочитал следующие предложения:

> хотите посмотреть наш сайт на **русский**

или

> как переключить интерфейс с английского на **русский**

Не могу понять эту логику. Почему здесь не использовали предложный падеж?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое предложение составлено неверно. Скорее всего, это опечатка: носитель языка так не скажет.  Правильно слово "русский" использовать в предложном падеже:

*Хотите посмотреть наш сайт на русск**ом**?* Посмотреть на каком языке? — на русском (языке).

Второе предложение верное, слово "русский" здесь стоит в винительном падеже:

*Как переключить интерфейс с английского на русск**ий**?* Переключить с чего на что? — с английского (языка) на русский (язык).

Comment: Все так, только это не опечатка, а результат адаптации программного интерфейса. Тут штука такая,Это "русский" скорее всего было подставлено из списка языком, которыми располагает система(типа английский, немецкий, португальский, японский.... и русский).. Заводить туда все падежи не всегда терпения хватит. Да и разработчики движка иногда просто не дают такой возможности. Нечто подобное имеет место сейчас в мессенджерах с тегами во фразах типа *Мы здесь обсуждаем **#линквистика***